# Update the web database using Android app?

Tags: android, http, webserver

I want to update the database of my website basically android app is getting data from pc it than process it and send it to the web database which store it and when ever android required that data it can get it from that database.
Now my question is how can I send it to the database at a specific place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you host the web server hosting the database. You could then package your data (in android) using JSON format, and send the data over using Httppost. Found a good example of code shown in https://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/26/the-simplest-way-to-post-parameters-between-android-and-php/ (although the web is just a PHP, you could then expand how to update PHP with MySQL etc). Hope this helps.